# The following program below works but a dialog box appears saying that the filename.exe has stopped working. Why so?

Tags: c, linked-list, codeblocks

This program is supposed to be a demonstration for deleting a node from a linked list.
The program works and output is the same as desired but soon after a dialog box appears saying that the executable file has stopped working. I used code-blocks as the IDE and C-programming language. I would like to know why that happened and how to avoid it happening in the future. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void create(struct node *first,int a[])
{
    struct node *t,*last;
    int i;
    first->data=a[0];
    first->next=NULL;
    last=first;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data=a[i];
        t->next=NULL;
        last->next=t;
        last=t;
    }
}

void display(struct node *f)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",f->data);
        f=f->next;
    }
}

int delete(struct node * f,int pos)
{
    int i,x;
    struct node *q=NULL;
    if (pos < 1 || pos > 5) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pos == 1) {
        q=f;
        f=f->next;
        x=q->data;
        free(q);
        return x;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++)
    {
        q=f;
        f=f->next;
    }
    q->next=f->next;
    x=f->data;
    free(f);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={3,5,7,8,9};
    struct node *first;
    int pos=4,t;
    first=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    create(first,a);
    t=delete(first,pos);
    display(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is strange to use pos and list, if you want to use offset or index, array can be better than list

Comment: It's not the cause of your error, but just as a general advice: casting the result of `malloc()` is not recommended, the preferred version would be `t=malloc(sizeof *t)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on display function where f is null

A solution is to remove the for loop and use a while testing if f is null or not.
I have also added a final `\n` to flush stdout

```
void display(struct node *f)
{
    while (f)
    {
        printf("%d ",f->data);
        f=f->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```